# do api documentation with swagger use live databases

Tags: api, swagger

I'm new to this api documentation era.

Vising this [api documentation](http://petstore.swagger.io), I get to post and query data. I understand that's a demo api documentation with swagger.

But what happens with real world API documentation? do I have a documentation in `demo.api.myawesome.com` and actual api on `api.myawesome. com` using different data stores?

But again digging deeper, I got to find out that an api can be self documenting using swagger [libraries](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore). This seems like both api and documentation are using the same data store which can't be the case.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why can't that be the case? if the api has proper authentication, there's nothing  you could do from the documentation that you couldn't do anyway via hitting the api in other ways. You won't be able to create/delete from the documentation unless you have a valid key.

Comment: wouldn't that be polluting live data with dummy/test data. Data from the documentation is test/demo data.

Comment: yeah, it certainly could. but that's no reason why it can't be done. Whether or not it's a good idea though is another issue entirely.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. or is it a common understanding that you will delete that data after testing?

Comment: well, no, my point is there's no "common practice" or "best practice" or standards at all with this. you do what makes sense with your setup. use a dummy db for it or don't.

Answer (score 1):

From the Swagger website:

> Swagger is a set of rules (in other words, a specification) for a format describing REST APIs. The format is both machine-readable and human-readable. As a result, it can be used to share documentation among product managers, testers and developers, but can also be used by various tools to automate API-related processes.

So yes, it uses the same "back end" as the actual API. It's just visualizing it, allowing you to interact with it via the Swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Swagger UI - the "try it out" button sends requests to the server specified by the [`host`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/) property in your spec. If `host` specifies your production server, requests will be sent to production; if it points to a sandbox, "try it out" will use the sandbox. You may have a version of the spec for internal use that points to production, and a public version that points to sandbox.

Note that Swagger supports [authentication](http://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) as a way to ensure that only authorized users (e.g. your actual customers with valid credentials or API keys) can make API calls.

You can omit `host` from the spec to disable the "try it out" functionality - this way you can still have the API docs, just without the interactive part.